# Fetching Taxonomy Slug

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to get taxonomy slug:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'locations' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        $term = array_shift( $terms );
    }
 ?>
```

I am then using the following code to output the slug:

```
<?php echo $term->slug; ?>
```

My question is, how can I use this to output two different taxonomies in the same location? For example:

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'locations', 'status' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        $term = array_shift( $terms );
    }
 ?>
```

I thought I could perhaps add terms 'location' , 'status' but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display two or more taxonomy then i think you should loop the $terms variable.

```
<?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'locations' );
    if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        foreach ($terms as $term):
            echo $term->slug;
        endforeach;
    }
?>
```

Hope its helps you.

Thank You

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have updated my answer to make it clearer. I am trying to use the above code to output two different taxonomies.

Comment: Its really depends upon what you want to output ?

Comment: I want to output the taxonomy slug.

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation for [`get_the_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/), only one taxonomy can be supplied. If you wanted to output the slugs of all the terms within two different taxonomies, you can do as Mohammad suggested, but twice.

i.e.

```
<?php

// output all slugs for the locations taxonomy
$locations_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'locations' );
if ( ! empty( $locations_terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $locations_terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;
    }
}

// output all slugs for the status taxonomy
$status_terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'status' );
if ( ! empty( $status_terms ) ) {
    foreach ( $status_terms as $term ) {
        echo $term->slug;
    }
}
?>
```

However, if you only care to get the slug of an individual term in each of the taxonomies, you may find [`get_term_by`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_by/) more useful.

i.e.

```
<?php
$loc_field = 'name';
$loc_field_value = 'special location';
$loc_taxonomy = 'locations';
$locations_term = get_term_by( $loc_field, $loc_field_value, $loc_taxonomy );
echo $locations_term->slug;

$stat_field = 'name';
$stat_field_value = 'special status';
$stat_taxonomy = 'status';
$status_term = get_term_by( $stat_field, $stat_field_value, $stat_taxonomy );
echo $status_term->slug;
?>
```